# Permission for chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I have background JS script, has written on Angular 2. When I run extension I have got this permission notification:

```
compiler.js:34069 Uncaught EvalError: Refused to evaluate a string as JavaScript because 'unsafe-eval' is not an allowed source of script in the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' blob: filesystem: chrome-extension-resource:".
```

`manifestfile` is:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Getting started example",
  "description": "This extension allows the user to change the background color of the current page.",
  "version": "1.0",
  "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self'",
   "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "index.html",
    "default_title": "Click here!"
  },

  "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "storage"
  ]
}
```

Which changes I should do?

Comment: Make sure you've reloaded the extension manually on chrome://extensions page. See also [ngCsp](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCsp).

Comment: any updates on this